# Why is app icon so blurry on iOS, when it looks fine at 1024x1024, How to fix this so image is clearer?

Tags: swift, xcode, image, app-store, appicon

I am using canva.com to create an app icon. I create it using 1024x1024 and plug it into the app icon generator which returns all the sizes for the icons. However, as the size decreases the image gets completely ruined to the point that it is completely illegible.

This is the original:
[image]

and this is the size that shows up on the users device (home screen icon):
[image]

It is completely blurred out and shows up this way on my device. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

You've designed your icon incorrectly. You have not planned for the size that it actually will be, so when your icon is shrunk, your strokes are all too thin and the image in the square is ridiculously small. You cannot make a small icon by shrinking a large icon; you need to supply both a large icon and a small icon, each drawn correctly.